# Sick days per month query - overlapping months sick leave applications

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a query to extract the number of sick leave days taken per month by employees. The problem with my query is that it does not account for any overlapping days. Eg sick leave could be from 29 March to 03 April. Therefore with my query below, this leave will not be captured, as its looking at the end date before March (to get all days taken in March).

How am I able to capture the overlapping days, eg it should only show March 29, March 30, March 31, so 3 days taken for month of march.

```
Select DISTINCT l.emp_number, l.leave_start, l.leave_end, l.leave_type, 
l.lve_days, e.division, e.location
FROM Leave as l Left Join Employees as E on l.emp_number = e.emp_number 
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
WHERE l.leave_start > = '2018-03-01' AND l.leave_end < '2018-04-01'
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "overlapping" - if you're querying by month, wouldn't you be able to run this query for each month, and then do some accumulation across months?

Answer (score 2):

These are the correct conditions for anyone who has taken leave in March 2018:

```
Select l.emp_number, l.leave_start, l.leave_end, l.leave_type, 
       l.lve_days, e.division, e.location
from Leave l Left Join
     Employees E
     on l.emp_number = e.emp_number collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
where l.leave_start < '2018-04-01' and l.leave_end >= '2018-03-01' ;
```

I removed the `select distinct`.  That should not be necessary and it just adds overhead to the query (for removing duplicates).

The `collate` on the `join` is suspicious.  This really shouldn't be needed for an employee number, which should have a canonical format.

If you want the number of days in the month, then you probably want a calendar table.  Not all days are likely to working days.

You can adjust the time period returned:

```
Select l.emp_number,
       (case when l.leave_start < '2018-03-01' then '2018-03-01' else l.leave_start end) as leave_start,
       (case when l.leave_end >= '2018-04-01' then '2018-03-31' else l.leave_end) as leave_end,
       l.leave_type, 
       l.lve_days, e.division, e.location
from Leave l Left Join
     Employees E
     on l.emp_number = e.emp_number collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
where l.leave_start < '2018-04-01' and l.leave_end >= '2018-03-01' ;
```

However, this will not adjust for non-working days.